# Mocking a method for @InjectMocks in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I facing the following problem. I want to mock a method which is inside the class which I want to test. Consider for the following example.

```
ExampleClass(){
    method1DependsOnMethod2(){
        // some code

        method2(){
            // some code

        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to test method1DependsOnMethod2 which depends on method2 but I want to mock the result of method2 to test only method1DependsOnMethod2.

I tried the following

```
@InjectMocks
@Spy
ExampleClass exampleClass

when(exampleClass.method2()).thenReturn()
```

or

```
doReturn(..).when(exampleClassmethod()).method2()
```

I also tried to use two instances

```
@InjectMocks
ExampleClass exampleClass
@Mock
ExampleClass exampleClassMock
```

but none of the approaches results in the desired.

I am thankful for any help

Greetings Matthias

Comment: The approach that you used, with `@Spy` should work.  You don't need the `@InjectMocks`.  So what went wrong?  Is there any error message?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response. Unfortunately, I am not able to look again until tomorrow. As far as I remember the method which should be mocked throws a NullPointerException since inside Mehtode2 I have to initialize a class.

Comment: `@Mock` and `@Spy` annotations are about what to mock, `@InjectMocks` is about where to inject mocked objects. They shouldn't be mixed.

Comment: As far as I understand it should work to use @Spy at exampleClass instead. I will try it again tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

as Dawood ibn Kareem mentioned, it works with @Spy.

I have to remove the @InjectMocks annotation, as WildDev mentioned, otherwise it seems that the "injected version" wants to initialize everything in the called method and do not mock it properly.

Furthermore I have to use

```
doReturn(bla).when(exampleClass).method1DependsOnMethod2();
```

I tried it with

```
when(exampleClass.method1DependsOnMethod2()).thenReturn(bla);
```

but this was also not working.

Thanks Dawood ibn Kareem and WildDev for your help.

Greetings Matthias